# Can't create connection to MySQL database on remote computer on my LAN

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, remote-access

I've succeeded in creating a connection from a Java application using Intellij to a MySQL database hosted locally but am having dreadful trouble making the same connection from identical code using a remote computer.

Both the local and the remote computers are running Windows 11.

I've done all the following:

1. carefully checked my connections string for my local connection:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false&user=TestUser&password=Test#Pass
```

... and my remote connection:

```
jdbc:mysql://192.nnn.nnn.nn:3306/testdb?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false&user=TestUser&password=Test#Pass
```

2. checked for the presence of my MySQL Connector/J driver (mysql.connector-java-5.1.49 is on my list of external libraries).
3. created a rule in the windows firewall allowing my client access the server through the relevant port (3306).
4. checked that the IP address and port of the remote host as well as the user name and password are all correct.  The IP address to the remote computer is the private IP address provided for that computer for private use within the LAN.
5. I've successfully created a connection to the database on the remote computer using MySQL based on the same IP Address, port, username and password. Does that mean the issue isn't a firewall problem?
6. I've also replaced "localhost" with 127.0.0.1 and with the private IP address (192.nnn.nnn.nn as above) when running the code locally on the DB host machine. The result is a successful connection every time.

I've also added the line to the code 'Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");' with the result that the code now no longer works even using a localhost string, yielding an error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver. This suggests that the driver used by the connection.jar is not com.mysql.jdbc.driver. The same happens for "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver". I've since commented this line out, and my localhost instance (of course) works fine again, while the remote instance (of course) reverts to a java.sql.SQLException: "No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql:..." error triggered on this line:

```
myConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString);
```

This is the central error I'm getting every time I try to create the remote connection from within the java application.

The output from the console when I run the local instance successfully is as follows (I've replaced the ip address here and in the stack trace for the unsuccessful instance with "192.nnn.nnn.nn"):

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.1\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.2.4\lib\idea_rt.jar=51949:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.2.4\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath D:\java_development\LessonsApp\out\production\LessonsApp;D:\java_development\Database_experiments\English_exercises\lib\mysql-connector-java-5.1.49.jar LessonsApp
jdbc:mysql://192.nnn.nnn.nn:3306/testdb?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false&user=TestUser&password=Test#Passjdbc:mysql://192.nnn.nnn.nn:3306/testdb?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false&user=TestUser&password=Test#Pass#1
```

Here's the stack trace for the unsuccessful remote connection (the connection is made at the press of a button from an initial screen and the :

```
"C:\Users\Jaime Hyland\.jdks\azul-15.0.10\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.3.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=57486:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.3.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Users\Jaime Hyland\IdeaProjects\LessonsApp\out\production\LessonsApp" LessonsApp
SQL exception: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://192.nnn.nnn.nnn.nn/testdb?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false&user=TestUser&password=Test#Passjava.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.sql.ResultSet.close()" because "rs" is null
SQL exception: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://192.nnn.nnn.nn/testdb?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false&user=TestUser&password=Test#Pass1Blah, blah java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.sql.ResultSet.close()" because "rs" is null
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://192.nnn.nnn.nn/englishexercises?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false&user=TestUser&password=Test#Pass
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:702)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:251)
    at ComboPopulator.getListForCombo(ComboPopulator.java:31)
    at CreateLessonGUI.<init>(CreateLessonGUI.java:105)
    at NavigationGUI$1$1.run(NavigationGUI.java:19)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:316)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://192.nnn.nnn.nn/testdb?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false&user=TestUser&password=Test#Pass
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:702)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:251)
    at ComboPopulator.getListForCombo(ComboPopulator.java:31)
    at CreateLessonGUI.<init>(CreateLessonGUI.java:117)
    at NavigationGUI$1$1.run(NavigationGUI.java:19)
```

I'd appreciate if anyone could provide me with a little guidance on this.  I'd particularly appreciate if anyone could clarify whether I can assume that my issue is not an obvious firewall problem if my local instance of MySQL Workbench can connect successfully with the remote MySQL Database using an identical IP address, port, username and password.

I've been back and forth through lots of stack overflow questions on jdbc connections looking for a solution. I apologise if I'm adding yet more duplication to this already much discussed issue.

Comment: Try first with a mysql client using the LAN IP address as the host part of the connection

Comment: Sorry, I should have made clear that the IP address I'm using is the private IP Address for use within the LAN. I'll edit the question accordingly.

Comment: I'm aware it's a private address. If you've set up the server correctly and your network functions as it should, the LAN hostname would be a lot better. Just to be clear, this 'remote' connection you're trying is *from inside* the LAN is it not? Because if it isn't, you will probably need port forwarding to forward to that host from 'the Internet'

Comment: If you can reach it on 192.nnn.nnn.nn from another sql client from the localhost then firewall is open. Can you set your sql client to not use SSL/TLS? Perhaps that DB is setup to insist on SSL/TLS. Your code & dependencies that reached the DB at localhost should be able to reach 192.nnn.nnn.nn unchanged (besides the  application.properties change to the spring.datasource.url). Is the version running at 192.nnn.nnn.nn materially the same as that running on localhost?

Comment: What stacktrace do you get locally (with the code/dependencies that work locally) when you call 192.nnn.nnn.nn? Does the DB at 192.nnn.nnn.nn have a schema testdb? Can you use the localhost's network ip (not 127.0.0.1) in place of 'localhost'? all of this info should narrow down the cause.

Comment: @g00se. Yes, everything is inside my home LAN. I'll research your comments and let you know when and if they work!  Thank you very much!

Comment: @John Williams: Thank you very much for your quick and comprehensive notes!  I'll research all your suggestions and get back to you as and when I have a result. I have to leave my desk now as it's St Patrick's Day and I'm Irish (though in Berlin). So I may not get back to you until the weekend!

Comment: @John Williams:  Inspired by your suggestions, one of the things I did with the code connecting remotely with the database was make sure it was identical to the code for the local machine. I simply overwrote the remote code with my git-saved version. I noticed a small difference in external dependencies. There was something wrong with my reference to the java-connection*.jar. Once I'd deleted and re-created the reference, things began to work (almost ... I have a new problem I'll try to work out for myself).

Thanks to everyone for your help (especially to you!).  I'll write an answer soon!